# Limit of term with roots

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I prove the following:

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{2}{3 (\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k-1})(\sqrt{k+2} + \sqrt{k})} = \frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: HINT: It looks set for using an appropriate kind of conjugate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We multiply by the conjugate of $\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k-1}$ and we use the asymptotic limit
$$\sqrt{k+a}\sim_\infty \sqrt k$$
we find

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{2}{3 (\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k-1})(\sqrt{k+2} + \sqrt{k})} =\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac23\frac{2\sqrt k}{4\sqrt k}=\frac13$$

Comment: So you multiply by $\sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k-1}$? But how do you get to $\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{ 4 \sqrt{k}}$? Could elaborate a bit on that? That would be great!

Comment: In the numerator we have $\sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k-1}\sim_\infty 2\sqrt k$ and in the denominator we have $(k+1-(k-1))(\sqrt{k+2} + \sqrt{k})\sim_\infty 4\sqrt k$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thanks! But how do you know that $2\sqrt{k}$ converges against 2?

Comment: What do you mean by converges against $2$?

Comment: I meant what's the limit of $\frac{2\sqrt k}{4\sqrt k}$ ?

Comment: You can cancel $\sqrt k$ and the limit is $\frac24=\frac12$.

Comment: Oh well, that must have been to obvious. Thanks so much! Now I figured it out :)

Comment: You're welcome IronMan;-)